# NPM run build not working in Windows specific directory

Tags: windows, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I am working on a Front End project in Javascript (NPM, Webpack and Babel). I work on Mac all the time but I am having some issues when cloning the project in my PC Windows 10 machine.

It is building properly if I put the project in any directory but when I put the project in the directory where it should be located, Babel doesn't compile the project as expected.

The reason the project should be located there is because I am integrating it with some other tools (Bamboo - Continuous Integration).

**npm run build**

My builds script is:

**"build": npm run clean && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --env.prod=true**

```
ERROR in ./index.js
Module parse failed: C:\opt\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\STA-DEV-
JOB1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js!C:\opt\bamboo-home\xml-
data\build-dir\STA-DEV-JOB1\src\index.js Unexpected token (24:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| const render = (Component, target) => {
|     ReactDOM.render(
|         <Provider store={store}>
|             <AppContainer>
|                 <Component/>
```

Does nodeJS or NPM or Webpack or Babel need specific permission over the directories they work on ?

Any help would be appreciated. I am lossing hair here.

Answer (score 0):

Am glad you are using window 10. Use the bash shell on windows 10 to run the command `npm run build`.
 follow this [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/) to learn how you can cd to the directory from the bash shell

Comment: What are file types under bamboo-home ? you may need different loader or exclude it in webpack.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, then i found that i need shell bash, so follow the bellow steps:

1. install [Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win)
2. go to project folder and right click to access context menu
3. from there run Git bash here
4. run the command: npm run build / yarn build

mine working perfectly with this solution.